# Json array to object

Tags: android, json

How can i convert this json array to a json object. And i need to store this json to a remote server. How can i do it. I cannot find a perfect tutorial for this purpose.

```
 private JSONArray getResults() {

    String myPath = "/data/data/com.example.sebastian.patientdetails/databases/" + "MyDBName.db";

    String myTable = "patients";


    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    String searchQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + myTable;
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);

    JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
        JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
            if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                try {
                    if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                        Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i));
                    } else {
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
        resultSet.put(rowObject);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    Log.d("TAG_NAME", resultSet.toString());
    return resultSet;
}
```

Comment: you can use rowObject.toString() and it will give you the string. Then you can send this string to remote server using network connection api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

    int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
    JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
    //new jsonarray
     JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
        if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
//new jsonarray of items jsonObject            
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {
                if (cursor.getString(i) != null) {
                    Log.d("TAG_NAME", cursor.getString(i));
                    object.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),cursor.getString(i));

                } else {
                    object .put(cursor.getColumnName(i), "");
                }
    //put  jsonarray
    jsonArray.put(object );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG_NAME", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    //put request jsonobject
    rowObject.put(jsonArray);
    resultSet.put(rowObject);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

you can use Google of Gson.jar,

Answer (score 1):

There is a method to convert json array into jsonObject,

```
JSONArray array;
for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(n);
    //do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: I think you have to add this code after getting the Json array  if your database is giving a JsonArray as response.